# Jquery animate to hover style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

is it possible in jquery to animate general tags like `a` or `div` to their corresponding hover styles without declaring a different classes for each tag/class?

For example `a` has `a:hover` in CSS standards, can I let Jquery tell to animate to that style instead of creating two different customs classes?

Comment: If you don't mind using [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions), then yes. Otherwise I think you'd have to explicitly animate between the various styles defined by `a` and `a:hover` (for example).

Comment: No.You can't make animation(anything) without a:hover class or specific class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot force an element to be styled as one of its pseudo-classes. These can only be applied by the browser itself.

Generally, you'd define your hover styles for both `:hover` and `.hover` so you can still apply the hover style with `addClass('hover')`.

```
a:hover, a.hover {
     // Fancy styling goes here
}
```

If your hierarchy goes deeper, you'll end up writing those two selectors quite a lot. Unfortunately, it's the only way (I know) to do this.